# Adding custom data-* attributes to tags while using the new(non-legacy) kotlin react wrappers

Tags: reactjs, kotlin, kotlin-js, kotlin-dsl

What's the equivalent of this:

```
<article
  id="electric-cars"
  data-columns="3"
  data-index-number="12314"
  data-parent="cars">
...
</article>
```

in react kotlin dsl non-legacy wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

The default solution is to use extensions.

```kotlin
    private const val DATA_COLUMNS_KEY: String = "data-columns"

    var HTMLAttributes<*>.dataColumns: Int
      get() = asDynamic()[DATA_COLUMNS_KEY]
      set(value) {
        asDynamic()[DATA_COLUMNS_KEY] = value
      }
```

and the way you use it:

```kotlin
    div {
      dataColumns = 3
    }
```

Explanation:

The way it works is you create an extension for `HTMLAttributes<*>` and create a setter for it. Since the setter will be using `asDynamic` it will include the property in the react html dom element.

Disclaimer:
I got this answer from [kotlin slack group](https://kotlinlang.slack.com/) :)